# conjunction of list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, binary-tree

i'm trying to solve such task: i have a list with int nums and i need to respond to requests "find the value of the bitwise AND of all integers in the range from L to R".
first line of input is N, Q positive int - N is list len and Q is number of requests
second line is N numbers (the list itself)
other lines are requests - each line has L and R boundaries
sample input:

```
5 4
2 5 3 4 1
1 3
4 5
2 5
2 3
```

output should be answer for each request
sample output for input above:

```
0
0
0
1
```

my code here:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

def bit_conjunction(lst):
  return reduce(operator.and_, lst, True)

n, q = map(int, input().split())
nums = list(map(int, input().split()))
requests = [tuple(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(q)]

for i, j in requests:
    left_ind = i - 1
    print(bit_conjunction(nums[left_ind:j]))
```

but time limit is 6 sec and 1 <= N <= 10^6 so my code needs optimising or even some more effective algorithm
(i tried to read about binary tree search but still don't know how to connect it with list and its indexes
so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint: you need to handle the already calculate values and not calculate them again, for example, (1,2) (1,3), (1,4), (1,5) . so how to you avoid them begin calculated again

Comment: the `bit_conjunction` function looks wrong, maybe feed `reduce()` with the first item of the list ( instead of `True`) and then the remaining list.

Comment: @magistar if execution time is important, and there is large dataset then why not

Comment: concerning your last edit:
Don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know how to delete your post, take a look at 
[**How does deleting work?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)

Comment: lol can u understand i need to delete this

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to do some preprocessing on the list first:

Per bit, collect how many numbers have a 0 in that bit as a running sum. So for the example input that would be:

| input | running counts of 0 per bit |
| --- | --- |
| 010 | 1, 0, 1 |
| 101 | 1, 1, 1 |
| 011 | 2, 1, 1 |
| 100 | 2, 2, 2 |
| 001 | 3, 3, 2 |

Now when we get a request, we can compare the counts that correspond to the end point with the starting point: if they are no different, then there was no 0 for that bit in that range, and so the conjunction of the whole range will have a 1 in that bit position.

Looking at it in more detail we actually need to look at the running counts *before* the starting point, and so we also need a 0<sup>th</sup> entry that has all zeroes in the above table.

Here is how that could be coded:

```
def preprocess(nums):
    n = max(nums).bit_length()
    counters = [0] * n
    return [counters] + [
        counters := [
            count + ((num >> (n-1-i)) & 1 == 0)
            for i, count in enumerate(counters)
        ]
        for num in nums
    ]

def bit_conjunction(counters, first, last):
    val = 0
    for a, b in zip(counters[first - 1], counters[last]):
        val = val * 2 + int(a == b)
    return val


n, q = 5, 4 
nums = [2, 5, 3, 4, 1]
requests = [(1, 3),(4, 5),(2, 5),(2, 3)]

counters = preprocess(nums)
results = [
    bit_conjunction(counters, *span)
    for span in requests
]
print(results)
```